# Modal Window in Net Core with ViewComponent

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

i have the problem with Modal Window open with JQuery. I don't call the function. The same Code with normal Page is open normaly but the call function inside viewcomponent don't call.
the razor Page contain one viewcomponent. This viewComponent have The modal window is call from JQuery function

the code of call function is:

```
<a href="#myModal" class="btnEditar btn btn-dark btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" title="Edit" 
data-id="@item.Id" Id="Edit">Edit</a>
```

and section script is

```
@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(".btnEditar").click(function (eve) {
        $(console.log("here click"));
        $("#modal-content").load("htmlpage.html");
        });
 </script>
 }
```

thanks very very much
Reagards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your modal is like:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

in your Compoent.

You can change your main view like:

```
<a href="#myModal" class="btnEditar btn btn-dark btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" title="Edit" Id="Edit">Edit</a>
@await Component.InvokeAsync("YourCompoentName")

@section Scripts
{ 
    <script>
        $(".btnEditar").click(function (eve) {
        $(console.log("here click"));
        $('.modal-content').load("../htmlpage.html");
    });
    </script>

}
```

Test result:

[image]